# Cross-Threading issue with listView

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0

OK before everyone post duplicate let me inform you I have looked at all those other post and im still lost some say use delegates or background worker etc... but how would I make this thread safe i want to delete the files on its own thread.

here is the code that i am working with.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cleanFiles.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void cleanFiles_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        // If so, loop through all checked files and delete.
        for (int x = 0; x <= listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
        {
            string tempDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems)
            {
                string fileName = item.Text;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, fileName);

                try
                {
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //ignore files being in use
                }
            }
        }
        PaintListView(tFile);
        MessageBox.Show("Files removed");
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ("Ready");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please put a check by the files you want to delete");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Reed mentioned, you cannot access UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread itself. So, you'll have to pass on a delegate `Control.Invoke()` to be executed with the UI Thread, like this

Try

```
    private void cleanFiles_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // If so, loop through all checked files and delete.
            for (int x = 0; x <= listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1; x++)
            {
                string tempDirectory = Path.GetTempPath();
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems)
                {
                    string fileName = item.Text;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectory, fileName);

                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //ignore files being in use
                    }
                }
            }

            PaintListViewAndSetLabel();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessageBox();
        }
    }

    private void ShowMessageBox()
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(ShowMessageBox), new object[0]);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Please put a check by the files you want to delete");
    }

    private void PaintListViewAndSetLabel()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action(PaintListViewAndSetLabel),new object[0]);
            return;
        }
        PaintListView(tFile);
        MessageBox.Show("Files removed");
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ("Ready");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help ! i am processing all the information !! ;] lol !

Comment: I tried the code above same issue do it freaks out on the if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0) do i need to move this out of the background worker and just use threads?

Comment: Usually getting something from a view should be fine; it's just setting something requires calling `Invoke()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't access any properties of your ListView (`listView1`) from the background thread (ie: anything inside of the `cleanFiles_DoWork` method) directly.  User interface controls can't be accessed on any thread other than the user interface thread.

You should, instead, make a list of the items to "clean" before calling DoWork, and pass these into the method via the [RunWorkerAsync overload taking an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx), and retrieve it in your method via [DoWorkEventArgs.Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx).

This will allow you to pass a list of items to process, process them in the background, then update your list when you are complete.

Comment: would please be so kind to show me an example with my code above?

Comment: you talk about making a list, is there a way when items are checked it adds that file with the path to an array ? then when you hit clean it sends that array list to the clean file method and then starting a thread and deleting the files ?

Answer (score 0):

Its bad idea to use control from background worker, I had the same problem recently with TreeView control. So the solution for Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls is [How-to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx) from microsoft. The main idea it checking safty using `InvokeRequired` property of your control and, if nessesary, run method invocation through `Invoke` method which is thread safe.