# background worker thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am trying to figure out the best way to keep my application responsive. Below shows the code that I am currently working with. What i have found is that the Background worker thread is the way to go.

```
    private void cleanFiles()
    {
            if (listView1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
            {

                // If so, loop through all checked files and delete.

                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems)
                {

                    string fileName = item.Text;
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(tFile + fileName);

                    try
                    {

                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        //ignore files being in use
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Files Cleaned");
                }


            }
            else
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("Please put a check by the files you want to delete");
            }

        }


    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to keep your program responsive is to use the `BackgroundWorker`.

```
List<string listWithFilenames = new List<string>();
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
bw.RunWorkerAsync(listWithFilenames);
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4852et58%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these questions:

[Cross-Threading issue with listView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625769/cross-threading-issue-with-listview)

[How to execute code in the GUI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718590/how-to-execute-code-in-the-gui-thread)

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the method you posted runs under the context of the UI thread,
all you need to do is wrap the logic (the `foreach` part)
in a method like :

```
private void DeleteFiles(object state)
{
/// your logic here
}
```

and call the `ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DeleteFiles));` 
from the cleanfiles method.

if you run .NET 4.0, you can use something like:

`Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => DoWork(null));`
then check the myTask status later , to see if its done.

Comment: im getting an error Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments